# Can an Alexa skill keep the microphone always on?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have been a C/C# developer for many years but haven't written any Alexa apps. I would like to write a skill to listen for baby babble (NOT WORDS) and respond in different ways. I would like my Alexa skill to keep the microphone ALWAYS on (similar to how "Alexa, Guard" works) because babies speak randomly.

Is there some sample code I can look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this.

There is no way to keep the microphone open with a custom skill.

When you activate the skill "open my skill", Alexa starts talking and then, when she stops, you have only 8 + 8 seconds to speak, otherwise, the session will be closed.

So you have 8 seconds, then if you don't speak there is a re-prompt phrase asking you to tell something, and another 8 seconds where you can speak.

If you don't, the session will be closed.

There is a way to keep the session open more than 8 seconds (playing some mute music for example), but the problem remains because you can only speak after that "music" is finished.